# Jquery not returning the unique values

Tags: jquery, html, django

I have created one viewall page for all the products in django and the page is created dynamically using the context object data. I have created one hidden input type which holds the value of unique id of products. When i click on the product i wish to fetch the value of hidden input type. But it is returning the value of first product only i.e the first object in the context. below is the code.

```
{% for album in list1 %}

    <div class="col-lg-3"  id="div1">
    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
    <input type="hidden" class="custId"  value={{ album.id }}>

  <div class="card-body">
      <a href="#"  class="k"><img src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-e646c987b3dcf11c9329af5070847f92.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="..." height="90px" width="85px"></a>
      <h5 class="card-title">{{ album.product_name }}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Category : {{ album.product_category }}</p>
      <p class="card-text" >Price : {{album.id  }}</p>



$('.k').click(function(){
            var a  = $('.custId').val();
            alert(a)
            console.log(a)
             $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have multiple a tags with `k` class. You can use something like this to access the specific `value` associated with the `k` class:

```
<div class="col-lg-3" id="div1">
    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <input type="hidden" class="custId"  value={{ album.id }}>
        <div class="card-body">
            <a href="#"  class="k"><img src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-e646c987b3dcf11c9329af5070847f92.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="..." height="90px" width="85px"></a>
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ album.product_name }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Category : {{ album.product_category }}</p>
            <p class="card-text" >Price : {{album.id  }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$('.k').click(function(){
            var a  = $('.k').parentElement.parentElement.children[0].value;
            alert(a)
            console.log(a)
             $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
```